# Virtualbox on virtualizes windows 10 shows only 32bit templates?

Tags: virtualbox, parallels, windows-10-desktop

I do not own any windows Host, I am trying to use an Ubuntu linux 64bit (16.04) on a virtualbox 5.2.12 on a virtualized Windows10 pro (64bit). This windows10 pro 64bit is hosted inside a Parallels 12 instance running on an OSX Sierra Laptop (a mac book pro). No Hyper-V enabled on windows, Windows (under System->About) says it is a full 64bit windows 10.

Of course it is easier to use the Linux machine directly but I need to do some tests in order to prepare a virtualbox linux virtual machine for both OSX AND WINDOWS10 systems (for a lecture, for students), so I need to see whether this 64 bit virtualbox linux machine is runnable from the virtualbox in OSX (it is) and from windows but I cannot load her yet because virtualbox is only showing / allowing 32bit machines - being running in the virtualized windows 10 of Parallels 12.

On some blog it is advised to "enable virtualization on BIOS" ... but which BIOS then in my case please? The BIOS in OSX does allow virtualization per default. The BIOS in the generated Parallels 12 Windows 10 machine is generated by Parallels. So either Parallels does something strange here or there is another bit to "turn" in order to allow virtualbox showing its 64bits templates ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [enable nested virtualization in Parallels](https://kb.parallels.com/en/116239)